# Extract value, procedure

Tags: oracle, procedure

Inicialmente eu precisava criar uma procedure que que lesse um arquivo xml e colocasse os dados em uma tabela oracle, crie a tabela, o diretório, tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
create or replace package body PACK_GUSTAVO1 as

v_id            INFO_XML.ID%type;
cursor C1 is    SELECT NVL(MAX(ID)+1,1) AS ID FROM INFO_XML;

PROCEDURE IMPORTA_XML IS
BEGIN

/* ABRE CURSOR */
    OPEN C1;
    LOOP
        /* LÊ UM REGISTRO DO CURSOR */
        fetch C1 into v_id;
         /* ABANDONA O LOOP CASO SEJA O FINAL DO CURSOR */
        EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    /* FECHA O CURSOR */
    CLOSE C1;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('proximo:' || v_id);

DELETE FROM INFO_XML WHERE ID=v_id;
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO INFO_XML (ID, CONTEUDO) VALUES
    (v_id, XMLTYPE(BFILENAME('CARGA_CSV', 'funcionarios.xml'), NLS_CHARSET_ID('WE8ISO8859P1')));
COMMIT;    

/* grava na tabela */

END;

end PACK_GUSTAVO1;
```

e o meu select extract value:

```
SELECT extractValue(CONTEUDO, '/funcionarios/contato/nome/value') as NOME FROM INFO_XML;
```

mas está dando erro, não sei o que fazer.

Comment: Que erro está ocorrendo ?

Comment: Motta,  Obrigado pela atenção, consegui um novo link no site do TOAD, lá me baseei e chegue até a minha estrutura atual:

Comment: http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/5998.loading-external-xml-files.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheguei a seguinte conclusão, por um link que achei do TOAD, postei nos comentários.
Atualmente estou aqui, e o que eu estou resolvendo é a questão do meu arquivo xml aparece com fonte japonesa na minha tabela, acreditei que fosse o cabeçalho do xml, mudar ele para UTF-8, para que ele conseguisse ler em meu dialeto... mas veio novamente a fonte japonesa, ou chinesa, não sei, rs'
Então decidi enviar os arquivos reais que eu tinha aqui.

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY TESTE2 AS


-- PARAMETROS PARA TESTE : CARGA_CSV , funcionarios.xml

PROCEDURE XXX( dir VARCHAR2, file VARCHAR2, name VARCHAR2 := NULL)  IS
 theBFile   BFILE;
  theCLob    CLOB;
  theDocName VARCHAR2(200) := NVL(name,file);
BEGIN 
DELETE FROM xml_documents;
    COMMIT;

  INSERT INTO xml_documents(docname,xmldoc) VALUES(theDocName,empty_clob())
  RETURNING xmldoc INTO theCLob;

  -- (3) Get a BFile handle to the external file
  theBFile := BFileName(dir,file);

  -- (4) Open the file
  dbms_lob.fileOpen(theBFile);

  -- (5) Copy the contents of the BFile into the empty CLOB
  dbms_lob.loadFromFile(dest_lob => theCLob,
                         src_lob => theBFile,
                         amount  => dbms_lob.getLength(theBFile));

  -- (6) Close the file and commit
  dbms_lob.fileClose(theBFile);  


DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Salvo com Sucesso !!!');

END XXX;


END TESTE2;
```